# What is the difference between `VAR=...` and `export VAR=...`?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

What is the difference in doing

```
$ MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
```

to doing

```
$ export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
```

and is there any side-effect of doing either in an SSH connection?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 1st one sets the value to the variable. For instance you can do

```
echo $MAVEN_OPTS
```

and have it return the value but if you would issue that outside your shell you will have an empty string returned.

In comes `export`.

Export is an instruction to the shell. It tells the shell to make this environment variable available to other programs executed from the same shell. Without the export, they are only available within the shell itself.

If you want the variable to be permanently available ssh reads `~/.ssh/environment`,`ssh2` reads `/etc/environment` and `~/.ssh2/environment`, and adds lines of the format VARNAME=value to the environment. From the [`ssh` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ssh.1.html#contenttoc9).

Comment: Though, if I issue the export within an SSH connection and the disconnect, that variable won't be available to subsequent connections. how do I make it permanent?

Comment: Of course it does not :) @pomario added in ssh and ssh2 methods for adding envs!

Comment: No, wait! :) What I mean is, I connect to the server using SSH and i want to add an environment variable that will be accessible to Jenkins web interface. is there any way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 9):

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
```

Sets a shell variable named `MAVEN_OPTS`. It is probably followed by an `export MAVEN_OPTS` command to make this variable available as environment variable to child programs, or a shell command that uses it like `java $MAVEN_OPTS ...`

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"
```

Sets a environment variable named `MAVEN_OPTS`. This environment variable is also available to child programs.

There are no side-effects except for that some java memory limits are adjusted for `maven` (a build system iirc).

Comment: darn it Lekensteyn. Thats's the 4th time today. Go do something else! >:D

Comment: @Rinzwind Doing so in #bumblebee on Freenode IRC :P

Comment: More than 2 good answer is not bad thing :)