# What's the difference between set, export and env and when should I use each?

Tags: command-line, bash

Every so often I'll bash out a bash script and it strikes me there are a few ways of setting a variable:

```
key=value
env key=value
export key=value
```

When you're inside a script or a single command (for instance, I'll often chain a variable with a Wine launcher to set the right Wine prefix) these seem to be completely interchangeable  but surely that can't be the case.

What's the difference between these three methods and can you give me an example of when I would specifically want to use each one?

<sub>Definitely related to [What is the difference between `VAR=...` and `export VAR=...`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128515/what-is-the-difference-between-var-and-export-var) but I want to know how `env` fits into this too, and some examples showing the benefits of each would be nice too :)</sub>

Comment: Note that `export key=value` is extended syntax and should not be used in portable scripts (i.e. `#! /bin/sh`).

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Let us consider a specific example. The `grep` command uses an environment variable called `GREP_OPTIONS` to set default options.

Now. Given that the file `test.txt` contains the following lines:

```
line one
line two
```

running the command `grep one test.txt` will return

```
line one
```

If you run grep with the `-v` option, it will return the non-matching lines, so the output will be

```
line two
```

**We will now try to set the option with an environmental variable.**

1. Environment variables set **without `export`** will not be inherited in the environment of the commands you are calling.

   ```
   GREP_OPTIONS='-v'
   grep one test.txt
   ```

   The result:

   ```
   line one
   ```

   Obviously, the option `-v` did not get passed to `grep`.

   **You want to use this form when you are setting a variable only for the shell to use, for example in `for i in * ; do` you do not want to export `$i`.**
2. However, the variable is passed on to the environment of that particular command line, so you can do

   ```
   GREP_OPTIONS='-v' grep one test.txt
   ```

   which will return the expected

   ```
   line two
   ```

   **You use this form to temporarily change the environment of this particular instance of the program launched.**
3. Exporting a variable causes the variable to be inherited:

   ```
   export GREP_OPTIONS='-v'
   grep one test.txt
   ```

   returns now

   ```
   line two
   ```

   **This is the most common way of setting variables for use of subsequently started processes in a shell**
4. This was all done in bash. `export` is a bash builtin; `VAR=whatever` is bash syntax. `env`, on another hand, is a program in itself. When `env` is called, following things happen:

   1. The command `env` gets executed as a new process
   2. `env` modifies the environment, and
   3. calls the command that was provided as an argument. The `env` process is replaced by the `command` process.

   **Example**:

   ```
   env GREP_OPTIONS='-v' grep one test.txt
   ```

   This command will launch two new processes: (i) env and (ii) grep (actually, the second process will replace the first one). From the point of view of the `grep` process, the result is *exactly* the same as running

   ```
   GREP_OPTIONS='-v' grep one test.txt
   ```

   However, you can use this idiom if you are outside of bash or don't want to launch another shell (for example, when you are using the `exec()` family of functions rather than the `system()` call).

#### Additional note on `#!/usr/bin/env`

This is also why the idiom `#!/usr/bin/env interpreter` is used rather than `#!/usr/bin/interpreter`. `env` does not require a full path to a program, because it uses the `execvp()` function which searches through the `PATH` variable just like a shell does, and then *replaces*  itself by the command run. Thus, it can be used to find out where an interpreter (like perl or python) "sits" on the path.

It also means that by modifying the current path you can influence which python variant will be called. This makes the following possible:

```
echo -e '#!/usr/bin/bash\n\necho I am an evil interpreter!' > python
chmod a+x ./python
export PATH=.
python
```

instead of running Python, will result in

```
I am an evil interpreter!
```

Comment: Why does GREP_OPTIONS='-v' grep one test.txt work?  I thought it needed a semicolon after '-v' (but I tried it and it does in fact work.)

Comment: Because with a semicolon, it is interpreted as two separate bash commands; the first one sets the variable (without exporting it), and the second starts with an environment that doesn't have the variable exported. Without the semicolon, however, this is one command (grep), preceded by setting a local environment.

Comment: Where do all the variables from `env` come from though? I mean when you open a new shell you always have a few variables. So some program must have `export`ed those, right?

Comment: @Pithikos Environment variables are set by "sourcing an environment."  By default, bash will source a system-wide bashrc (or profile.d or bash_profile).  Then it sources your user ~/.bashrc (and/or ~/.bash_profile).  Either of these files can contain bash commands to source other scripts, so you can ultimately have environment variables coming from all over the place.

Comment: What about `set var=blah`?

Comment: @January What does SET GREP_OPTIONS='-v' will do referring to above example ?

Comment: I think you should emphasize that `env` also doesn't affect the current shell environment variables (`env` changes the environment variables in a new process). I looked at another post and clarify that by myself.