# How to launch interactive shell script in bash hourly with cron?

Tags: bash, xorg, cron

I put this line in the crontab:

```
1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/user/Desktop/mltpl
```

The script is executable.

If paste that command in the terminal--that is, the string without stars, it works perfectly:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/user/Desktop/mltpl
```

I tried:

```
sudo service cron restart
```

But the problem persists. How can I get `cron` to run that command hourly?

---

Update. Got it working with ROOT crontab:

```
1 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/user/Desktop/mltpl
```

Comment: This makes no sense

Comment: The approach proposed by the OP is not a good idea because within this approach the ownership of some files and directories inside `/run/user/<uid>/dconf/` will be changed, thus some errors will be generated. Please read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/955591/566421) answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess my first guess about the way the `DISPLAY` variable is handled is wrong. I think the problem somehow related to `cron` using a non-interactive shell. A test script using an infinite `read` loop failed to run. However, when I tested by opening a new tab:

```
* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal --tab -e /home/murukesh/test.sh
```

it worked fine.

---

According to this [SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/415424/how-do-i-make-cron-run-a-java-gui-application) and this [Ubuntu Forums post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=185993), you may have to either `export` the `$DISPLAY` variable or use `env`:

```
1 * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/user/Desktop/mltpl
```

(or)

```
1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/user/Desktop/mltpl
```

This maybe due to the shell used by `cron` being `sh` and not `bash` (see [What's the difference between set, export and env and when should I use each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205688/whats-the-difference-between-set-export-and-env-and-when-should-i-use-each)).
Also have a look at [Script doesn't run via crontab but works fine standalone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone).

Comment: Thanks for answer! But both options didn't work. ls -l /usr/bin/gnome-terminal gives -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 301520 Dec 16  2013 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal. So I used root crontable: * * * * * env DISPLAY=:0.0 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e /home/user/Desktop/mltpl 2>/home/user/Desktop/crondbg. In crondbg: ** (gnome-terminal:20533): WARNING **: Could not open X display. No protocol specified. Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:. Any idea?

Comment: @ngc3o34 please don't accept answers until your problem has been solved. That said, programs in `/usr/bin` are usually always owned by root, so that doesn't mean anything. Using root's crontab because `gnome-terminal` is owned by `root` won't help. What error do you get when you use your own `crontab`? Also, is you `DISPLAY` actually `:0.0`? Check with `echo $DISPLAY` in a normal terminal.

Comment: nothing. empty crondbg

Comment: echo $DISPLAY gives ":0" but DISPLAY=:0.0 also works in terminal

Comment: new method works in terminal. cron still resist to participate. only result is crondbg updated, but nothing inside. may be I should set another variable like PATH? just guessing...

Comment: @ngc3o34 probably. If the script isnt private, can you post it here? Use http://paste.ubuntu.com and add a link in the question. There might be some other assumption.

Comment: Alternatively you could try to wrap the command in `bash -c '...'`.

Comment: @Sparhawk was one of the first things that I tested. Didn't help.

Comment: I think script has nothing to do with that. Because this: DISPLAY=:0 vlc works, and this: DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal doesn't

Comment: @muru 2>/home/user/Desktop/crondbg  at the end

Comment: @ngc3o34 and `* * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/gnome-terminal` is silently failing?

Comment: @muru if using user's crontab - yes

Comment: I found that `export DISPLAY=:..` is not enough in most cases. Check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/955591/566421).