# The difference between "echo" and "export" an environment variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

The environment is Ubuntu 18.

If I add one line `JAVA_HOME="/usr/java11"` in /etc/environment, and execute `source /etc/environment` , I can echo this environment variable:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java11
```

But if I try to get it from export, this variable is not in the list:

```
export | grep JAVA_HOME
--result is blank--
```

Then I use `export $JAVA_HOME=/usr/java8` to export a variable (notice here is java8, not java 11),  I can have:

```
export |grep JAVA_HOME
declare -x JAVA_HOME="/usr/java8"
```

Now, I can still `echo $JAVA_HOME` as /usr/java11:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java11
```

Question: what is the difference of `echo $variable` and `export | grep JAVA_HOME`?

I try a simple python program, `os.environ.get("JAVA_HOME")` returns "/usr/java8" from the export, not the echo.

Comment: You mention Ubuntu 18, so is this a *contained* Ubuntu Core 18 or *snap* only environment? as the *confinement* models in play in 18 releases differ to the more open 18.04 models - please be specific.

Comment: I think the issue here is that `/etc/environment` is just a list of name=value pairs. When it is read by `pam_env` those variables are exported to the environment, but sourcing it into your current shell only creates ordinary shell variables - check with `declare -p JAVA_HOME` for example.

Comment: @steeldriver , what is "ordinary shell variables", and what are other variables?

Comment: @guiverc sorry I don't know what is 'contained' and what is 'snap'. It is a docker container created from 'FROM ubuntu:18.04'

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is a different product to the 18 products; Ubuntu normal *deb* based releases (without containment) use the *year.month* format; differing from the 18 or *year* based products that use containment. Ubuntu has had *year* based products since 2016 - you should be precise as 18 & 18.04 represent different products (a 18 release cannot use a *deb* package - it's *snap* only)    fyi:  *confinement* models can vary on snap; but if you're familiar with containers you ~know this; it's the ~same with different terminology..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between set, export and env and when should I use each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205688/whats-the-difference-between-set-export-and-env-and-when-should-i-use-each)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is not really the difference between `echo` and `export`, but rather the difference between an *environment variable* and a simple *shell variable* (and also about how the `/etc/environment` file is normally used).

In particular, although `/etc/environment` happens to contain lines of the form `name=value` that are valid as POSIX shell variable assignments, its primary purpose (in a modern Linux system) is to be read by the `pam_env` module during initialization of a user's session - it is `pam_env` that exports them to the user's environment.

When you source `/etc/environment` into your shell, there's no special magic that tells the shell that the assignments are those of environment variables (which are exported to the environment, and hence inherited by sub-processes) rather than regular shell variables (which are just available in the current shell scope).

Next time you log in, `pam_env` will do its magic and `JAVA_HOME` *will* then appear in the output of `export | grep JAVA_HOME`.

See also

- [Difference between shell variables which are exported and those which are not in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/what-scopes-can-shell-variables-have)
- [What scopes can shell variables have?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/what-scopes-can-shell-variables-have)

Comment: Thanks to point out the difference between "shell variable" and "environment variable".

Comment: "environmental variables" technically also are "shell variables". They are a subset.

Answer (score 5):

`echo`  and `export` are very different commands in the first place.

- `echo` will display text. In `echo $JAVA_HOME`, the shell will substitute $JAVA_HOME with the contents of the shell variable JAVA_HOME it it is defined. Otherwise, `$JAVA_HOME` will return an empty string.
- `export` provides the "export" attribute to the shell variable. `export JAVA_HOME` will set the export attribute, i.e., the variable will also be available in the environment of any sub shell or sub process rather than in your current shell only. If the variable is not yet set, you can define it while exporting as in `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java11`.

In `/etc/environment`, environment variables are registered with the syntax of a variable assignment. The content of `/etc/environment` in a default Ubuntu install indeed can be executed. So if you execute the line you included:

```
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/java11`
```

Then, all that will do is assign the shell variable PATH the current value.

However, because you included the variable in `/etc/environment`, it should be effectively be exported during the next startup of your system. Then, it should exist in `export` and show up in `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the first terminal you open. So what you currently observe is because you did not yet restart the machine after modifying `/etc/environment` (and did not export the variable in other ways).

Answer (score 3):

Building on the other answers here, some commands that parallel `export` but for other categories of variables are `set` (which works for e.g. `VARIABLE=value` then `set | grep VARIABLE`) and `env`

Each of these three commands, when given no arguments, prints a list of variables; which variables they will print has to do with the kinds of variables the command manages.

See [What's the difference between set, export and env and when should I use each?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205688/whats-the-difference-between-set-export-and-env-and-when-should-i-use-each)

`echo $VARIABLE` always works since all kinds of variables can be read as `$VARIABLE`; however, this means it gives you no information on what kind of variable it is or where it comes from.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is a command for printing text and variables to stdout (or redirect).

`export` lists the current exported variables in the shell.

This thread explains why you would use `export` much better than I can:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411455/what-does-export-do-in-shell-programming ... it does a great job explaining what export is fo