# In which system file does 'export' command make changes?

Tags: command-line, bash, java, filesystem, environment-variables

I installed java-8 using a PPA. After that I gave a command:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

I had heard somewhere that this command does temporary changes. But after many logouts and logins, these commands below still works (I think due to that `export ...` command):

```
java -version
javac -version
```

But when I give the command:

```
export -p
```

It shows a list of environment variables, but in that list, does not show variable `JAVA_HOME`. Moreover, I wonder how the commands `java` and `javac` still works!

Can someone tell me in which file `export` command make changes? Are they temporary or permanent? And what else happens above? Please elaborate!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`export` is a shell command. It affects the current running instance of the shell. It does not make changes in any file. The changes are temporary, only in effect until the shell exits. Once you set a new variable in the shell, to make it available to other programs started from it, you `export` it. See:

- [What is the difference between Terminal, Console, Shell, and Command Line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/506510/158442)
- [What is the difference between `VAR=...` and `export VAR=...`?](https://askubuntu.com/q/128515/158442)
- [What's the difference between set, export and env and when should I use each?](https://askubuntu.com/q/205688/158442)

`java` and `javac` might work because you installed Java using a PPA, and the installation automatically added these commands to the `PATH` ([What is the PATH environment variable and how do I add to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-path-environment-variable-and-how-to-add-it)). Specifically, just checking the version shouldn't need the `JAVA_HOME` variable. Whether you set it or not makes no difference just for that. And apparently [`JAVA_HOME` is used by other applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2025295/2072269), not the Java compiler or the JVM.

Comment: I checked the file `/etc/environment`, but there is nothing like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle...` assigned in the **PATH** variable. Then what else might be happening?

Comment: @AnkurShah run `type -a java javac`. Are those directories in your `PATH`?

Comment: I typed the command and I get this: `java is /usr/bin/java` , `javac is /usr/bin/javac`. And I also saw `/usr/bin` in PATH variable. I think I get it now! Is it?

Comment: @AnkurShah that's it. The PPA you used installed the commands to `/usr/bin`, which is already in `PATH`, so no changes to `PATH` were needed. `JAVA_HOME` is for other software, so just the `java` and `javac` commands will work without it.